# 13.04 GNOME doesn't turn off

Tags: gnome, 13.04

When I want to turn off my computer with Ubuntu 13.04 GNOME and I writing in terminal command

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

appearing black screen and the computer is still working.
I using with driver: NVIDIA for Xorg, VDPAU with nvidia-310.
I using with computer: Acer Aspire-Z5710.

I will be thankfull for answer :).

Comment: I have the same problem on a Acer Aspire Happy 2. It will never shutdown. I have to hit the Power Button to do so. But on my Acer Aspire 5750G shutdown works. So I think it's related to BIOS and/or video BIOS and/or ACPI. That's all I know.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get update` and then do `sudo shutdown -h now`

Comment: @Mitch This doesn't help :(

Comment: Try this; `sudo poweroff`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it also doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install systemd-shim
```

and then restart